# Why does Codeigniter have a Model class with only a constructor and a get?

Tags: codeigniter, oop

Can someone tell me why Codeigniter has a Model class that's almost bare?  What does this design accomplish?

```
1: <?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
 2: /**
 3:  * CodeIgniter
 4:  *
 5:  * An open source application development framework for PHP 5.1.6 or newer
 6:  *
 7:  * @package     CodeIgniter
 8:  * @author      ExpressionEngine Dev Team
 9:  * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2008 - 2011, EllisLab, Inc.
10:  * @license     http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/license.html
11:  * @link        http://codeigniter.com
12:  * @since       Version 1.0
13:  * @filesource
14:  */
15: 
16: // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
17: 
18: /**
19:  * CodeIgniter Model Class
20:  *
21:  * @package     CodeIgniter
22:  * @subpackage  Libraries
23:  * @category    Libraries
24:  * @author      ExpressionEngine Dev Team
25:  * @link        http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/config.html
26:  */
27: class CI_Model {
28: 
29:     /**
30:      * Constructor
31:      *
32:      * @access public
33:      */
34:     function __construct()
35:     {
36:         log_message('debug', "Model Class Initialized");
37:     }
38: 
39:     /**
40:      * __get
41:      *
42:      * Allows models to access CI's loaded classes using the same
43:      * syntax as controllers.
44:      *
45:      * @param   string
46:      * @access private
47:      */
48:     function __get($key)
49:     {
50:         $CI =& get_instance();
51:         return $CI->$key;
52:     }
53: }
54: // END Model Class
55: 
56: /* End of file Model.php */
57: /* Location: ./system/core/Model.php */
```

I see the __get function, but I'm not sure that's doing to help me.  How will extending this class help my design?

```
39:     /**
40:      * __get
41:      *
42:      * Allows models to access CI's loaded classes using the same
43:      * syntax as controllers.
44:      *
45:      * @param   string
46:      * @access private
47:      */
48:     function __get($key)
49:     {
50:         $CI =& get_instance();
51:         return $CI->$key;
52:     }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So whenever you extend the `CI_Model` class your models will inherit the `__construct` and `__get` functions both of which are [Magic Methods](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php).

The `__construct` function will be called whenever you call a function in your model.  All it does is just create a log message.

```
function __construct()
{
    log_message('debug', "Model Class Initialized");
}
```

However its useful because say you are calling a model in your controller which for some reason isn't working.

```
$this->load->model('Model_name');
$this->Model_name->function();
```

At least you'll be able to check the logs to see if the model was loaded -  useful for debugging.

The `__get` method is used for

> utilized for reading data from inaccessible properties.

Again this is useful because it will allow you to **access any of the CI libraries in your model**.  For example you will be able to use the session library in your model - `$this->session->userdata('username')`.  **Without** the `__get` function in `CI_Model` trying to access the session library in your models would error.  However by extending `CI_Model` it won't.  So bearing that is mind its quite useful

Comment: Thanks.  I think that is my problem.  How does it make it so you can access any of the CI libraries?  I don't think I understand the syntax.

Comment: @johnny For example if do `$this->session->userdata('username')` in your model.  The `session` part (e.g the name of the library will get passed to the `__get()` method.  Then in that method the `get_instance` function is called.  That function returns the Codeigniter Super Object which can be used to access the core libraries.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: This is a great answer because its a common mistake to assume that all of the CI libraries can only be called in the controller. For example I think its worth encouraging people to do form validation in the model (not the controller).  Thanks for posting.